# How do I scrape the text that appears when I mouse-hover the element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tooltip, screen-scraping, mousehover

On website https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i9-11900K+%40+3.50GHz&id=3904
I tried to scrape all the tool-tip information, the price and date of CPU in "Pricing history" section

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i9-11900K+%40+3.50GHz&id=3904')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='placeholder']/div/canvas[2]")))

for el in element:       
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()   
    mouseover = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.SELECTOR, ".placeholder > div > div.canvasjs-chart-tooltip > div > span")))      
    print(mouseover.text)
```

But the outcome says: 'WebElement' object is not iterable.
Is there anything I have to modify? Or is there any other good way to scrape all the mouse-hover information of price and date in the 'Pricing History' section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the time/prices from the graph into a pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = (
    "https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i9-11900K+%40+3.50GHz&id=3904"
)

html_text = requests.get(url).text

df = pd.DataFrame(
    re.findall(r"dataArray\.push\({x: (\d+), y: ([\d.]+)}", html_text),
    columns=["time", "price"],
)

df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"].astype(int) // 1000, unit="s")
print(df.tail())
```

Prints:

```
                   time   price
236 2023-05-28 06:00:00  317.86
237 2023-05-29 06:00:00  319.43
238 2023-05-30 06:00:00  429.99
239 2023-05-31 06:00:00  314.64
240 2023-06-01 06:00:00   318.9
```